# Function getgrgid() returns NULL when it is called by nobody

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

I take LTP (Linux Test Project) on embedded device. Device stuck in following while loop in test case setfsgid03, because `getgrgid()` always return `NULL` when it is called by `nobody` .
It works fine when it is called by `root` on embedded device. And it works fine on x86 linux host when it is called by `nobody`.

Is it caused by any configuration of linux on device?

Relevant code snippet is below:

```
gid = 1;
while (!getgrgid(gid))
    gid++;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "works fine, called by nobody"?

Comment: @schorsch312: Most probably, it means when the user ID corresponds to the user name 'nobody' (often user ID `-2`), then the `getgrgid()` call fails.  When it is called by 'root' (usually user ID `0`), it succeeds.  No information is given for other users.  The user ID for 'nobody' is used with NFS to map root accesses to a remote file from 'extremely privileged' to 'very unprivileged'.  That may be a factor in why the code behaves as it does — or I may be completely wrong.

Comment: `getgrgid()` sets `errno` when it fails - so try using `perror("getgrgid")` if it fails to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

`getgrgid` will read the entries from `/etc/group` or with Glibc more generally from sources specified in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. If `/etc/group` does not exist or it doesn't have other groups besides the `gid` then this code will loop at least until the wrap-around/signed overflow of `gid`. If there is *only* the entry for `nobody` at pid `-2` it will also take ages to find that `pid`.

All in all, the code is **utterly bad**. I'd just ensure that there is an entry in `/etc/group` with GID 2 say; the *proper* way to find a defined non-root gid would be to use `getgrent_r` successively until the returned record has `gr_gid` != 0, and fail if NULL is returned before such a record is found.